# How do I divide a complex string into 3 seperate arrays?

Tags: javascript, string, arrays

**Here's where I am:**
I started with an array...cleaned it up using 'regex'.
Now I have this...each item has three values

- mystring = 4|black|cat, 7|red|dog, 12|blue|fish

**Here's where I want to be:**
I want to end up with three arrays.

- array1=("4","7","12")
- array2=("black","red","blue")
- array3=("cat","dog","fish")

I also want to do this without leaving the page...preferably using javascript
I understand the theory, but I'm getting tangled in the syntax.

Comment: You started with an array, you want to end with multiple arrays … why make the detour via a string? What did the original array look like?

Comment: I hear ya, but it actually started off much more complicated...I had a PHP SOAP response - - "Method","ItemNo,1|23|book1,4|34,book2,32|340|book3" - - which I needed to pull 2 variables from (Method & ItemNo) leaving me with a value that I pushed into a third variable(this silly string), part of which will be used to populate a dropdown. I'm sure it's not the most eloquent process, but it's also been a learning process, lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use John Resig's famous ["search and don't replace"](http://ejohn.org/blog/search-and-dont-replace/) method here, it's perfect for it:

```
var arr1 = [], arr2 = [], arr3 = [],
    mystring = "4|black|cat, 7|red|dog, 12|blue|fish";

mystring.replace(/(\d+)\|([^\|]+)\|([^,]+)/g, function ($0, $1, $2, $3) { 
    arr1.push($1);
    arr2.push($2);
    arr3.push($3);
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kzcQA/)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the split() method :

```
var res = mystring.split(','); //will give you an array of three strings
var subres = res[0].split('|'); //will give you an array with [4, black, cat]

//etc...
```

Comment: Once you have it like that, you could just grab the first indexes of each array to make your array one and do the same with 2 and 3. This seems like a good idea, provided I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
var values = mystring.split(',');

var arrays = new Array();

for(var i=0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var parts = values[i].split('|');
    for(var j = 0; j < parts.length;j++) {
        if(!arrays[j]) {
            arrays[j] = new Array();
        }
        arrays[j].push(parts[j]);
    }
}
```

Will give you an array that contains those three arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
   var str = '4|black|cat, 7|red|dog, 12|blue|fish';

   var tmp = str.split(',');

   var firstArray = Array();
   var secondArray = Array();
   var thirdArray = Array();

   for( var i in tmp ){
        var splitted = tmp[i].split('|');
        //alert(true);
        firstArray[i]=splitted[0];
        secondArray[i]=splitted[1];
        thirdArray[i]=splitted[2];
   }
```